# Pass JavaScript var's value to ASP MVC method?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

```
@{
  Project1.Controllers.HomeController.Method1(ID, Cust_Name);
}
```

In above, how to pass ID (int) and Cust_Name (string) from Javascript?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call server side code with client side variables... You will have to look into perhaps using AJAX or some other way of getting the variables back to the server.

Consider the JQuery ajax method: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I meant to say Pass values from JavaScript to MVC method.